# Seeking improvement recommendations for my PROD deployment process

Tags: git, deployment, production-environment, e2e-testing

I'm looking for a more robust, cheap option for production deployment of my node backend.

Currently my method is to run E2E tests locally, then at around 2AM I'll `ssh` into the production server, pull a release tag from my prod branch in git, restart all the scripts, and then run E2E tests again with fingers crossed.

It feels very cheap and there must be a better way. Is there something that would be able to automate this deployment process, including running my E2E tests, maybe notifying a Slack channel when it's done? Something that knows what release version is currently deployed. Whats the current best practice for deployment and what's the next step up from my current practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better  practice would be to formalize that deployment process as a [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), which would be part of your sources, and be used by any Jenkins server (2.x).

Jenkins has a [Slack plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin), so that job will be able to interact with a Slack channel.